# Combine two mysql queries with different where clauses

Tags: mysql, subquery, union

I have results across multiple locations. The locations are stored in one table and the results in another. I query every result with a location in the netherlands.
I group those results by the province their in. After wich i use the lattitude, longitude to mark the results per province at google maps.

The query:

```
SELECT   loc.location_id as loc_id, loc.lat, loc.long, count(res.unique_id) as aantal, loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats 
FROM     `vj_results_1618048029` AS res, vj_location AS loc 
WHERE    res.time > '1324635105' AND res.time < '1327313506' AND res.search_id='8070' AND (loc.lat != '0' AND loc.long != '0') AND res.location_id != '' AND res.location_id = loc.location_id  AND loc.land = 'Nederland'
GROUP BY loc.provincie 
ORDER BY loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats DESC
```

The result:

```
loc_id  lat         long        aantal  land        provincie       gemeente    plaats
19      52.132633   5.291266    5732    Nederland            
672     52.926438   6.791355    670     Nederland   Drenthe         Borger-Odoorn   Borger
67      52.518537   5.471422    597     Nederland   Flevoland       Lelystad        Lelystad
401     53.1641642  5.7817542   812     Nederland   Friesland            
52      51.842867   5.854622    3486    Nederland   Gelderland      Nijmegen        Nijmegen    
63      53.2193835  6.5665018   890     Nederland   Groningen       Groningen       Groningen
185     50.9555426  5.8248384   670     Nederland   Limburg         Sittard-Geleen  Geleen
183     51.5657089  5.081203    3241    Nederland   Noord-Brabant   Tilburg         Tilburg
168     52.632281   4.750806    6044    Nederland   Noord-Holland   Alkmaar         Alkmaar
223     52.3116551  6.9268283   1324    Nederland   Overijssel      Oldenzaal       Oldenzaal
37      52.0901422  5.1096649   2291    Nederland   Utrecht         Utrecht         Utrecht
2723    51.5332946  4.2162383   413     Nederland   Zeeland         Tholen          Tholen
65      51.924216   4.481776    5842    Nederland   Zuid-Holland    Rotterdam       Rotterdam
```

The problem is that the lattitude longitude i recieve are those of the narrowest location of the first result in the group. For flevoland it is the city 'lelystad' and for zeeland the town 'tolen'. In 'friesland' its accurate because the first result did not specify a town, just the province.

To get the right lattitude and longitude i would query something like this:

```
SELECT   location_id as loc_id, loc.lat, loc.long, loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats 
FROM     vj_location AS loc 
WHERE    (loc.lat != '0' AND loc.long != '0') AND loc.land = 'Nederland' AND loc.gemeente = '' AND loc. plaats = ''
GROUP BY loc.provincie 
ORDER BY loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats DESC
```

Wich would give me these results:

```
loc_id  lat         long        land        provincie       gemeente    plaats
19      52.132633   5.291266    Nederland            
697     52.9476012  6.6230586   Nederland   Drenthe      
1257    52.5279781  5.5953508   Nederland   Flevoland        
401     53.1641642  5.7817542   Nederland   Friesland        
235     52.045155   5.8718234   Nederland   Gelderland       
2732    53.2887213  6.7060867   Nederland   Groningen        
860     51.4427238  6.0608726   Nederland   Limburg      
255     51.4826537  5.2321687   Nederland   Noord-Brabant        
407     52.5205869  4.788474    Nederland   Noord-Holland        
884     52.4387814  6.5016411   Nederland   Overijssel       
3796    52.119508   5.1943653   Nederland   Utrecht      
3692    51.325362   3.6640464   Nederland   Zeeland      
705     52.0207975  4.4937836   Nederland   Zuid-Holland
```

I need to combine those to a single query, with the results and the group from the first query and the lattitude and longitude from the second. Could anybody assist?

Thanks in advance

*edit: 
I tried it using a UNION but it returns a error :
1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns*

I tried using subqueries but it slows the query down.. It now takes ages to run a query

*2nd edit: Thanks to @johntotetwoo i edited the union query to make it work.
I had to remove the order by because my mysql did not like that, did not need it really was for the readability while debugging.
I also changed the order of the select in the second query so that the zero's where put at the right column.*

*The new query*

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT   loc.location_id as loc_id, loc.lat, loc.long, count(res.unique_id) as aantal, loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats 
    FROM     `vj_results_1618048029` AS res, vj_location AS loc 
    WHERE    res.time > '1324635105' AND res.time < '1327313506' AND res.search_id='8070' AND (loc.lat != '0' AND loc.long != '0') AND res.location_id != '' AND res.location_id = loc.location_id  AND loc.land = 'Nederland'
    GROUP BY loc.provincie
           UNION
    SELECT   location_id as loc_id, loc.lat, loc.long, 0 as aantal, loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats 
    FROM     vj_location AS loc 
    WHERE    (loc.lat != '0' AND loc.long != '0') AND loc.land = 'Nederland' AND loc.gemeente = '' AND loc. plaats = ''
    GROUP BY loc.provincie) as iTable
```

It works great now, thanks!
I just wondered if it could be combined to 1 row (i now have a row with the nr. of results and the province, and another row with the same province and the right longitude and lattitude.) If those could be combined it would be completely perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Add the field aantal to the second query and re-union

Answer (score 0):

it it because the second query doesn't have `aantal` column.

try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT   loc.location_id as loc_id, loc.lat, loc.long, count(res.unique_id) as aantal, loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats 
    FROM     `vj_results_1618048029` AS res, vj_location AS loc 
    WHERE    res.time > '1324635105' AND res.time < '1327313506' AND res.search_id='8070' AND (loc.lat != '0' AND loc.long != '0') AND res.location_id != '' AND res.location_id = loc.location_id  AND loc.land = 'Nederland'
    GROUP BY loc.provincie 
    ORDER BY loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats DESC
           UNION
    SELECT   location_id as loc_id, loc.lat, loc.long, loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats , 0 as aantal
    FROM     vj_location AS loc 
    WHERE    (loc.lat != '0' AND loc.long != '0') AND loc.land = 'Nederland' AND loc.gemeente = '' AND loc. plaats = ''
    GROUP BY loc.provincie 
    ORDER BY loc.land, loc.provincie, loc.gemeente, loc.plaats DESC) as iTable
```

Comment: It works great now, thanks!
I just wondered if it could be combined to 1 row (i now have a row with the nr. of results and the province, and another row with the same province and the right longitude and lattitude.) If those could be combined it would be completely perfect!